# How to remove add to cart button text in the view.phtml

Tags: magento-1.6

I want to remove add to cart button text only, not the button itself, because I'm using background image instead a text.

I mean the (add to cart)button in the view.phtml Page .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 'add to cart' text does not reside in view.phtml. you need to go to:

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

and find the code below:

```
$buttonTitle = $this->__('Add To Cart');
```

change it to:

```
$buttonTitle = $this->__('');
```